# Differences between 1+1D & 3+1D (background) electric field?

Tags: electromagnetism, quantum-field-theory, electric-fields, quantum-electrodynamics, pair-production

in Sidney Coleman's paper [More about massive Schwinger model](https://doi.org/10.1016/0003-4916(76)90280-3) ([PDF](https://sci-hub.ru/https://doi.org/10.1016/0003-4916(76)90280-3)). Section 2 "The origin of $\theta$" P.242 (beneath the eq. 2.5). Discuss about some differences between 1+1D & 3+1D electric field with background field $F$, Coleman's paper said that:

[image]

In 3+1D, *"it is always energetically favorable for the vacuum to emit pairs until $F$ is brought down to zero"*. Which means an background field $F$ in 3+1D is trivial thus it wouldn't matter.

In 1+1D, "*it is not energetically favorable for the vacuum to produce a pair if $F\leq \frac{1}{2}e$*". Which is non-trivial, thus raise the $\theta$ term in Schwinger model.

My question is, why in 3+1D the pairs production is always possible thus $F$ can always strictly be $0$ ? Shouldn't we consider the energy conservation law will prohibit pair production when $F$ is less than an threshold value? Or I miss some thing important in 3+1D?

Comment: You are correct that pair production screens charge in any dimension, all the way down to the fundamental charge. The difference is that this fundamental charge generates a field that decays with distance, *except* in 2d, where it generates a field that is constant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. This essentially boils down to the discrete and constant nature of the electric field$^1$ $$E~=~\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{q_i}{2\epsilon_0}{\rm sgn}(x-x_i)\tag{1}$$ of $n$ point charges $q_1, \ldots, q_n$ at positions $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ in 1+1D.
2. While in more than 1+1D, the attractive Coulomb energy between a particle and an anti-particle gets dwarfed in comparison to the repulsive separation energy in the background electric field $F$, this is no longer true in 1+1D.
3. To derive the upper limit $|F|\leq\frac{e}{2\epsilon_0}$ for the background electric field $F$ in 1+1D mentioned by Coleman, here is one approach: Consider the energy density
   $${\cal E}~=~\frac{\epsilon_0}{2}\left(F + \frac{e}{2\epsilon_0}{\rm sgn}(x-b) - \frac{e}{2\epsilon_0}{\rm sgn}(x-a)\right)^2\tag{2}$$
   of the electric field after a pair separation. Let us assume $F,e>0$. Then $0<a<b<L$. (The other cases are similar.) The relevant pieces are the cross-terms (ct)
   $$\begin{align} {\cal E}_{\rm ct}~\stackrel{(2)}{=}~& \frac{Fe}{2}\left[{\rm sgn}(x-b)- {\rm sgn}(x-a)\right]\cr &-\frac{e^2}{4\epsilon_0}\underbrace{{\rm sgn}(x-b) {\rm sgn}(x-a)}_{=1+{\rm sgn}(x-b)- {\rm sgn}(x-a)}\cr
   ~=~&\frac{e}{2}(F-\frac{e}{2\epsilon_0})\left[{\rm sgn}(x-b)- {\rm sgn}(x-a)\right] -\frac{e^2}{4\epsilon_0}.
    \end{align}\tag{3}$$
   The corresponding energy is the integral
   $$ \begin{align} \int_0^L\! dx~{\cal E}_{\rm ct}~\stackrel{(3)}{=}~&\frac{e}{2}(F-\frac{e}{2\epsilon_0})\left[|x-b|- |x-a|\right]_0^L-\frac{e^2}{4\epsilon_0}\left[ x \right]_0^L\cr
   ~=~&  -\frac{e}{2}(F-\frac{e}{2\epsilon_0}) 2(b-a)-\frac{e^2}{4\epsilon_0}L
   .\end{align}\tag{4}$$
   In particular, pair separation is energetically favorable iff $F>\frac{e}{2\epsilon_0}$.

---

$^1$Eq. (1) follows from [Gauss' law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_law)
$$\frac{dE}{dx}~=~\frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0}~=~\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{q_i}{\epsilon_0}\delta(x-x_i)\tag{5}$$
in 1+1D.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm very greatful to your answer. There is still something (I might overthinking) I'm confusing, when follow Coleman's discussions, we should only consider the electric field that lie between the particle and anti-particle (of cause, and $F$), is that reight? Seemingly when we consider entire system incliuding two outmost condenser plates (even when particle reach the condenser plate might cause some charge neutralization effect), things getting too intricate